# How to include token in policy in azure api management?

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-management

I'm using a token that works in postman when included in body of form-data for a post request. How can I include the token in a policy ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the token as 'Authorization' header of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending the token to the request body inside the inbound tag solved the problem.

```
        string temp = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true); 
        temp = temp + "&token={{MyTokenName}}";
        return temp;
```